# How do I connect to ftps server with port number through php?

Tags: php, ftps

I want to connect to an ftps server with PHP. I am using `ftp_connect()`

In my ServerURL `ftp_connect('example.google.com:7080')`

But I get this warning when I try to connect:

> Warning: ftp_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

```
  <?php

$ftp_server="example.google.com";
$ftp_port="7080";
$ftp_serusername="example";
$ftp_serpass="Pass@123";

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server,$ftp_port) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 

// login with username and password
//if($conn_id){
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_serusername, $ftp_serpass); 
//}

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    exit; 
}

// upload the file
//$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY); 

// check upload status
// if (!$upload) { 
//     echo "FTP upload has failed!";
// } else {
//     echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
// }

// Retrieve directory listing
$files = ftp_nlist($conn_id, '/remote_dir');

// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id);


?>
```

now i got this error

> Warning: ftp_login(): Login incorrect. in C:\xampp\htdocs\serve\remotedirect.php on line 12
>   FTP connection has failed!

Comment: `Login incorrect` should be obvious.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is using StackOverflow as a live debugging tool, e.g. adding problems to the question once one the original issue was fixed. This will make for confusing answers.

Answer (score 3):

Port should be second parameter. Check documentation:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-login.php

Also for FTPS you should use other function:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php

Comment: Can you please fix that error because i cant open my server folders and files now i send code please chack that code

Comment: You should add a code sample to your answer to improve it. Link only answers are note really welcome on SO, even when they go to a credible source. They still can die someday and the answer gets useless.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I think that if the official documentation dies then not only answer gets useless but also a question as well.

Comment: @GBoomanikandan
Your code is fine now, I've just run it and it's working ok. Double-check your login, password, server address and it's port number. Other then that, code you've pasted is working for plain FTP (not secure) connections.